# Series of questions about ER diagram and database?

Tags: database-design

I have newly learned about ER diagrams and how powerful they are.

I am trying to make a very basic ER diagram for hospital and there are few questions and doubts in my mind.

This is the ER diagram that I've made:

[image: er diagram of hospital]

I want tests to be stored in hospital database as well as in the patient's report file(all the tests of a specific patient should be stored in his/her report file).

The ternary relationship test should signify that:

- A patient and a doctor maintains only one report
- A doctor makes a report for specific patient
- A patient and his report can have tests from N no of doctors.

**Q1-** But I am confused how to achive this using ternary relation?

**Q2-** What is the difference between 3 binary relationship and 1 ternary relationship(and also which of them carrys more information)?

**Q3-** Can a relationship can have it's own prime(key) attribute?

**Q4-** If we have concept of surrogate key then why does weak entity exists in first place?

**Q5-** How to conclude which entity should be made weak and whichshould be not?

**Q6-** Any good source to learn EER ,advanced topics of database designing(relational algebra,etc..) and about ternary relationships(I have searched youtube and google but none of them was satisfactory)?

Comment: I'm not sure how powerful Chen diagrams (the type of diagram you provided) are in the real world, I almost never see them outside of someone's CS homework.  This question is also overly broad and you may want to revise.

Comment: There is a reason why you have seldom seen Chen diagrams,  except in CS homework.  This kind of diagram provides a picture of the Subject Matter data, and **not** a picture of the database design.  There is a lot of overlap, but there is a lot of difference as well.  It's the difference between analysis and design.  There are many professionals who have studied a lot about design,  but almost nothing about analysis.  This is unfortunate.

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where 1st stuck following a published information modeling & DB design method.

Answer (score 1):

Q1:  Why do you need a ternary relationship?  Test is a relationship between a patient and a doctor.  What is the third entity you need to specify in order to pin down a specific instance of a test.  I assume that a doctor can order more than one test for a given patient.

Q2:  They carry different information.  One of them is appropriate in any given situation, and the other does not carry the needed information.

Q3:  In the Chen ER model,  relationships are generally not given a primary key attribute.  Instances of the relationship may be identified by identifying each of the participants in the instance.

Q4: There is more than one way to skin a cat.

Q5: Make an entity weak if it can have no existence outside the context of the related strong entity.  Invoice detail line is a weak entity.  There will never be an invoice detail line without a corresponding invoice.

Q6:  There are hundreds of good textbooks to learn more about database design.  The ones by CJ Date are classics.  There a re a few good sources on EER,  but most good sources on ER will  incorporate EER concepts.  Here is a link to ternary relationships, but it repeats stuff you already know.  [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/N-ary-Relationship-in-Database#:~:text=N-ary%20Relationship%20in%20Database%201%20Unary%20Relationship.%20When,a%20binary%20relationship.%20...%203%20Ternary%20Relationship.%20](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/N-ary-Relationship-in-Database#:%7E:text=N-ary%20Relationship%20in%20Database%201%20Unary%20Relationship.%20When,a%20binary%20relationship.%20...%203%20Ternary%20Relationship.%20)  the primary value to you is the terminology of N-ary relationships.  This should help you google.

You didn't ask this,  but you need to know it anyway.  There is a difference between analyzing the subject matter  (hospitals),  and designing a database to hold the relevant data.  People who do not understand the difference often end up producing the right solution to the wrong problem.